# Create file on another server

Tags: java, windows, ftp

How would I create a file in another windows server?  The server has a username, and password, ip address and specific directory.

Comment: There is no need to add language name to the tittle, try always use tags for this.

Comment: This should do what you are asking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705600/ftp-upload-via-sockets

Comment: @igor: Unless you think the keyword is important enough that it should show in the related questions list, close as duplicate list, links, ... in fact tags are not a substitute for putting important information in the title.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for clarification, but I was trying to point OP only to not put language tag like `Java:` in the beginning of the title, as this is not usually welcome on SO. But your comment is completely correct.

Comment: @Mike are you conversant with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @orm already points out, this is answered already here [FTP upload via sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705600/ftp-upload-via-sockets/2705662#2705662)

Basically, you could reuse an existing library like [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) to do it. For the specifics of using the FTP client have a look at the [documentation for the class FTPClient class](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

Answer (score 1):

[SAMBA](http://jcifs.samba.org/)! Braziiillll, Braziiiiiiillll!

Something like this:

```
String userPass = "username:password";
String filePath = "smb://ip_address/shared_folder/file_name";

NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(userPass);
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(filePath, authentication);
SmbFileOutputStream smbFileOutputStream = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(smbFileOutputStream);
//You should be good from this point on...
```

NOTE: The destination folder needs to be shared first!